# Unwanted mod_rewrite behaviour

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just did a fresh install of lamp stack on ubuntu and enabled the mod_rewrite module for my default website. What I want is something similar to the drupal's queries, when the whole query string is kept in one variable. For this purposes the following mod_rewrite code may be used:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem begins when some a string starts with the name of the file already existing in the directory;
For example if I open a page: `http://localhost/home/blablabla` - the contents of $_GET are as follows:

```
Array ( [q] => home.php )
```

What I want to see is:

```
Array ( [q] => home/blablabla )
```

I think it's something with default website or mod_rewrite configuration, but I just couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to exclude the `home.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or you exclude every existing file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The reason: The [`L` flag causes an internal redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) with the new rewritten URL. And the new URL `home.php` is also matched by the expression `^(.*)$`.

Comment: Excluding the existing files (and directories) by using the command above is pretty handy, however, in this case the $_GET shows up as empty...

Comment: MultiViews could cause this bahavior. Try to disabled it. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews

Answer (score 0):

Not *exactly* an answer to your question, but isn't that what _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] and _SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] are for?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need the recently added [DPI] flag to discard PATH_INFO with multiple per-directory rewrites.